# How to analyze this sentence in a tree diagram?

Tags: syntax, english, syntax-trees, analysis, sentences

I tried to draw a tree diagram of this sentence

> In 1816 they were purchased by the British government and from then on displayed in the British Museum.

but it leads nowhere. I think I'm fine until "and from the on..." but how can I link this sencond part to the rest? Is the coordinator and on the same level as the PP (In 1816), NP (they) and VP (were purchased (PP by (NP the (N' british government))? 
Could anyone give me a hint how to proceede or even a suggestion of a full diagram?

Comment: Strict parallels (with *they were* deleted in the second clause) linked by *and*. *In 1816* = *from then on*, *they were* = *∅*, *purchased by the British government* = *displayed in the British Museum*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework.

Comment: OP at least showed some effort so I'm voting to keep this open :)

Comment: @jlawler I can't find anything that explicitly bans homework-related questions. The OP doesn't appear to be hiding the fact that it's homework (although an explicit "this is part of an assignment" would be nice) and has made some effort to complete the question themselves. Surely we could come up with some answers that help the OP find the solution they need without giving them an explicit solution.

Comment: To restate @StoneyB's point in a simpler way (since I'm not very good at syntax and I was a bit confused at first), if you add "they were" to the second clause you'll see that it could be an independent sentence. Review how to deal with *conjunctions* and *elision* in your diagrams and I think you'll find your answer.

Comment: OK, I guess I was going with the policy from ELU. However, the question is incoherent. What kind of "tree diagram"? Of base structure or surface structure? With or without deleted material? A derivation is what's needed; a tree structure explains nothing except one step in a derivation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.